# Problems to load tidyverse and dplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I try to load tidyverse I get this message:

```
library("tidyverse")
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘dplyr’ 1.0.2 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required
> Además: Warning message:
> package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.3

Comment: Reopen R and install `tidyverse` again using `install.packages("tidyverse")`

Comment: You need to upgrade